# joining two tables adding selective data in sql oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

these are my tables

```
C_ID  USAGE B_ID
4     100   2
2     400   1
3     200   2
1     300   1
```

and

```
B_ID  ZONE_NAME
2     central
1     west
```

and here is my query,

```
select 
    sum(usage)  
from 
(
    select 
        usage_679.c_id,
        usage_679.b_id,usage_679.usage,
        zone_679.zone_name 
    from usage_679 inner join zone_679
        on zone_679.b_id = usage_679.b_id
)
where zone_name like 'w%';
```

problem is that it can print data related to west zone only.I want to print both zone name with total usage in respective zone.

expected output

```
zone_name  sum(usage)
1            700
2            300
```

Comment: in,expected output it should be names of zone , not 1 and 2. right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [SQL FILLDE LINK FOR SAMPLE EXECUTION](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/944d0/14/7) . You don't need **WHERE** condition . You can achieve via **GROUP BY**

```
select 
    sum(usage),zone_name  
from 
(
    select 
        usage_679.c_id,
        usage_679.b_id,usage_679.usage,
        zone_679.zone_name 
    from usage_679 inner join zone_679
        on zone_679.b_id = usage_679.b_id
)
group by  zone_name
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| SUM(USAGE) | ZONE_NAME |
--------------------------
|        700 |      west |
|        300 |   central |
```

Even this would work: (No need of 2 SELECTS)

```
SELECT
    sum(USAGE),zone_name

    FROM usage_679 INNER JOIN zone_679
        ON zone_679.b_id = usage_679.b_id

GROUP BY  zone_name
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
| SUM(USAGE) | ZONE_NAME |
--------------------------
|        700 |      west |
|        300 |   central |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP BY` clause to attain the result. Please try.

```
select 
    zone_679.zone_name,
    zone_679.b_id,
    SUM(usage_679.usage)
from usage_679 inner join zone_679
    on zone_679.b_id = usage_679.b_id 
group by zone_679.zone_name, zone_679.b_id;
```

Comment: no it give same zone name twice and doesn't really add respective usage.

Comment: Please add the expected output in question.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on @priyanks answer... if you only want the results for the west you add a `having` clause i.e

```
SELECT
sum(USAGE),zone_name

FROM usage_679 INNER JOIN zone_679
    ON zone_679.b_id = usage_679.b_id

GROUP BY  zone_name
HAVING zone_name like 'w%' --Filter added for result
```